# Adding strict search to multiple fields with a single textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Have a basic angular app,

**HTML**

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="txt.name" />
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="d in data | filter: txt:strict">
      <span>{{d.name}}</span>
      <br />
      <span>{{d.description}}</span>
      <br />
      <span>{{d.loremipsum}}</span>
      <br />
    </li>
  </ul>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("mc", function($scope){

$scope.data = [{
  'name': 'asd',
  'description': 'jiocioasdiasidjpoasdko',
  'loremipsum': 'loremipsum'
}, {
  'name': 'qwe',
  'description': 'poqwpeqwpe',
  'loremipsum': 'loremipsum'
}, {
  'name': 'czxc',
  'description': 'asdasdasd',
  'loremipsum': 'loremipsum'
}]
});
```

I want to be able to search by both `name` and `description`, but not by `loremipsum`

How can I do this?

[Example on JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/terovohoru/1/)

Comment: if it's by `name` OR `description`, then you'd need a custom filter or a custom filter function

Comment: @NewDev yes, it's an `OR`

Comment: Then you need to write a custom filter function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your custom filter please see demo below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("mc", function($scope) {

  $scope.data = [{
    'name': 'asd',
    'description': 'jiocioasdiasidjpoasdko',
    'loremipsum': 'loremipsum'
  }, {
    'name': 'qwe',
    'description': 'poqwpeqwpe',
    'loremipsum': 'loremipsum'
  }, {
    'name': 'czxc',
    'description': 'asdasdasd',
    'loremipsum': 'loremipsum'
  }];
});

app.filter('customFilter', function() {
  return function(items, string) {
    var filtered = [];
    var stringMatch = new RegExp(string, 'i');
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var item = items[i];
      if (stringMatch.test(item.name) || stringMatch.test(item.description)) {
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    }
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="mc">
  <input type="text" ng-model="txt.name" />
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="d in data | customFilter: txt.name">
      <span>{{d.name}}</span>
      <br />
      <span>{{d.description}}</span>
      <br />
      <span>{{d.loremipsum}}</span>
      <br />
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way I can pass arguments (searchable fields) to the custom filter instead of hardcoding to `name` and `description`? so I can use this across other data models as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using a custom function: 
[custom function solution](http://jsbin.com/fadigujapi/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

You will probably want to use match instead of === in the custom function.